# Solution of the equation $\frac{\log x}{x}=1-\frac{1}{a}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I'm just a high school guy so this question is hopeless for me. I don't know advanced mathematics. I'm trying to get $x$ in terms of a. When I try to cancel the $\log$ by substitution, exponential functions appear. Is there some way to at least approxumate $x$ in terms of $a$ by using infinite series or anything else?

Comment: There isn't a closed form for x in terms of elementary functions. Your solution will involve the Lambert W function. Solving the simplified equation log(x)/x = a results in x = -W(-a)/a.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $y=1/x$. Then taking the antilogarithm,

$$ye^y=e^{1/a-1}$$ which is solved by the Lambert function

$$\frac1x=y=W\left(e^{1/a-1}\right).$$

You won't find a simpler expression.

Comment: What's Lambert function? What is it's formula or infinie series?

Comment: @Dove: Wikipedia is your friend.